# KMplayer - how to change the size of the texts on screen(NOT the subtitles)

Tags: kmplayer

I wanted to know how to change the size of the texts on screen, like when you press "Tab" button and it shows the information of the video file but they are really small and hard to read, or the text on the upper left side of the screen showing you the percentage of the volume but it's so small I can't even read it in full screen!

since I'm here, how do I assign a default screen size for the player? I remember the older version(which I was using until now) had an option in the screen menu of the options to assign a default screen size and if you close your player in a bigger or smaller size, the next time you launch it, the player will be in the pre-assigned size.

I know how to change the size of the subtitles, but that doesn't affect the texts I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for anyone interested, I found it out myself:

first of all, don't install the 64X, for some reason it doesn't have the same options menu as the other version and its options are really really really limited compared to the normal version.

but if you have the 64X version, it's under the tweaks menu in the options(by pressing the F2 button) it's called OSD and you can change the size and the font of it.
if you have the normal version of KMPlayer it has almost 20 times more options for literally everything including the OSD messages.